# Improving SaveApplicationData performance

Tags: core-service

I'm currently using the core service `SaveApplicationData` method - sequentially adding new application data to both a specific subject (TCM URI) and to the global application data namespace. This involves potentially thousands of individual calls in succession.

Functionally, this works as intended - but the performance of these repeated save calls is causing a bottleneck. A couple of questions:

1. Is there any way that I can batch up multiple `SaveApplicationData` calls into a single call. I notice the docs mention that multiple `ApplicationData` instances can be saved at once - so I could at least batch up the global application data into one call. But presumably the subject specific application data will always have to be saved individually?
2. Is there a more efficient way of storing user-specific data via the core service? I considered creating a new schema field to store this information whilst creating the components - but this application data isn't something that I wish to expose to end users. I'm also loathe to set-up a separate persistence mechanism just for storing this sort of user data.

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### API

The Content Manager Core Service API Reference Guide has:

```
void SaveApplicationData(
    string subjectId,
    IEnumerable<ApplicationData> applicationData
)
```

Of the two parameters, we have:

**subjectId**

"The identifier (TCM URI or WebDAV URL) of the subject to which the application data should be associated. Use null to save global application data."

**applicationData**

"The application-specific data to save. Multiple ApplicationData instances can be saved at once."

It looks like for a given subjectId, we can definitely save multiple sets of ApplicationData, but I don't see a SaveApplicationData method that takes in multiple subjectIds.

**I think you're right that "subject specific application data will always have to be saved individually."**

### User-Specific Data

You can use permissions with components and schemas, but you can also change the timing of your script or refactor the logic if possible.

You can use **permissions** to control both the creation of components based on a "configuration" schema as well as on the ability to see or edit the components by removing `read` permission on the containing folders for both.

To avoid needing a component maybe consider **changing the timing of your script**--use Application Data but only update as needed per user, schedule the update during off hours, and/or "chunk" the updates into smaller requests.

Just like content modeling, if you have a pattern in the data, you can definitely **abstract out the differences** and only save a "type" (integer) or reference to the full values stored elsewhere. The trade-off, of course, would be longer retrieval times.

Comment: Thanks Alvin. I can probably live with the performance bottleneck for now - but it's useful to have these alternatives to consider.

Answer (score 3):

With 2011 there's not much you can do there. In 2013 there is an additional process added to Tridion allowing you to execute `Batch Operations` (functionally equivalent to the old `Multiple Operations` method in the COM API).

I guess for now your best approach would be to start making these changes using the Asynchronous methods available to the CoreService - some detail available [here](http://amarchuk.blogspot.nl/2013/03/asynchronous-operations-with-coreservice.html).

Comment: Thanks Nuno. I'll take a look at the Async methods - but will have to translate to Java first :)